# Appium missing DOM objects behind screen view

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

For example I take an aliexpress app. As you can see on screenshot, only visible part of the screen is represented in Appium App Source window.
Is it Appium or Android related? Is it possible to force one of them to return full DOM?
[image: appium_missing_DOM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour: 
Appium on **Android** returns DOM **only for screen visible part**.

In contrast, on **iOS** it gets the full DOM - that can be a huge performance issue if you are using Xpath locators.

You can get less on Android by setting `ignoreUnimportantViews` capability but there is no way to get full DOM at once.

To get elements that are not visible you need to swipe and here you have several options:

- swipe with [TouchActions](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/)
- use UiAutomator native functionality like [UiScrollable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html)